# Does the tag [devops] really fill any gap between author and questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Actually [devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devops) has 713 questions, most of them multi tagged and where the fact the author is in a devops team or the tools can help in "devops" organizations doesn't bring anything to the question.

The few questions only tagged [devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devops) are off topic as "too broad" or "mostly opinion based".

What is the community position on this tag ?

---

There's also [devops.se](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) which I moderated for a while.

Comment: Looks like a meta tag. I'd hold of a bit on burninating, it could be a good way to find questions that should be closed.

Comment: @Stijn didn't though about this usage :) Makes sense

Comment: Thanks, I added it to the [Ignored Tags] in my profile.  Don't kill the tag please.

Comment: @HansPassant Indeed, I forgot to say most questions looks like (or are blatantly) crap. But as I didn't had a look over the first page I didn't wish to be too categorical.

Comment: I love burning tag for the same reason Hans hate it, it puts question in front of people that are able to close them.

Comment: @Braiam yes because there is no queue with 8.5k entries that already does this :)

Comment: Weird... it's a sponsored tag...

Comment: Well, but then everyone has to wake up to the smell of burning tag in the morning. No one likes that, having a homepage cluttered with closed, garbage questions.

Comment: @Cody I'm unsure of what you mean, that we should leave this tag be or that  if there's any cleaning to do it must have a burninate-request beforehand ?

Comment: That burninations are frustrating because they make the homepage unusable for me for at least a day and prevent me from finding questions that I want to answer. There really needs to be a better way, but there isn't. Not your fault, of course. It was more a response to Braiaim's reply to Hans.

Comment: @Cody aww, ok, I assume the solution is to have a tab with your tags of interest to replace the homepage during those days. But on this one there's good chance some questions will pop-up anyway on tags you follow.

Comment: @CodyGray well, if we simply vtc those questions as they should, the clutter of off topic questions will be just spread over everyones' homepage all the same, just a tick higher.

Comment: @Braiam This is enforcing people to do "reviews". Which I don't think any SO rule enforce at all. I mean anyone is free to moderate or not, being part of SO doesn't include you have to do a minimum review/close votes per day.

Comment: @Braiam Devil's advocate on my previous comment: Then those people not willing to do reviews should accept to be bothered/distrubed once in while by other's effort to clean up the site.

Comment: I'm not enforcing anyone to do anything, it's just a side effect of putting light on the most obscure corners of SO.

Comment: @Braiam that was my idea, I did split it on 2 comment so everyone can vote on their favorite position :) Yet I'm still unsure of which way to take actual position seems in favor of cleaning it up (if I interpret votes properly), but I'll wait before bumping this Q next week before doing anything.